# Unwanted page number on part page (memoir)

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I have a pretty huge latex book. And I get an unwanted page number on 1 out of 3 part page. I tried to remove packages one by one, but can't figure out where's the error, and can't make an MWE.

So the file is - https://github.com/marx-in-ua/das-kapital/blob/master/tex/book.ii.tex In style file https://github.com/marx-in-ua/das-kapital/blob/master/tex/style.sty#L48 I set part pages to empty style:

```
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
```

And it works on part 1 and 3, but for some weird reason shows page number on part 2:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please always post full but minimal examples, not links to external sources that might rot over time

Comment: I mentioned that I was trying hard - but currently my MWE is 500 tex files.

Comment: We cannot go though your entire project to debug it for you. You need to minimize to the smallest possibile

Comment: I tried cloning your project. I cannot even compile it without errors

Comment: Additionally, it is not really nice to people wanting to help that you redefine `\chapter` to the `\part`. So please start over with your question and provide something others can test

Comment: Found it. I'll do an answer after lunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Your redefinition of `\beforepartskip` is flawed.

Her is your code:

```
\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\cleardoublepage\null\vspace{3cm}\noindent\hspace{1.5cm}}
```

But the point is, this macro is only meant to control the vertial spacing of the part bare, i.e. the spacing above the title. So the `\cleardoublepage` is wrong.

The pseudo code for `\part` is similar to this

```
If open right: # the default
   \cleardoublepage
Else:
   \clearpage
End If
\thispagetyle{part}
# an irrelevant two column test
\beforepartskip
... # the rest of the part formatting
```

Thus when you also have `\cleardoublepage` inside `\beforepartskip` the `\thispagetyle{part}` is no longer guaranteed to be on the same page as the title.

The default for those three skip commands are

```
\newcommand{\beforepartskip}{\null\vfil}
\newcommand{\midpartskip}{\par\vskip 2\onelineskip}
\newcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil\newpage}
```

As noted none of them contains `\cleardoublepage`.

Unrelated: You might want to look up `\vspace*`.

BTW: here is my cut down MWE, then one just needs `kapital.cls`, `fonts.tex` and `style.sty`. No need for 500 tex files.

```
\documentclass{kapital}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
   \mainmatter

   \kant[1]
   
   \chapter{1}

   \kant[1]
  
   \chapter{2}

   \kant[1]

   \chapter{3}

   \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated my question: added MWE without my classes at all. And now I understand where the error is. Thanks.

Comment: And is there a way that my parts start on right and chapters on any?

Comment: @DenysPotapov Please don't do that, now my answer makes no sense. Please post a new question instead

Comment: Ok, I achieved it with `\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vspace{3cm}}` - not that elegant, but works. Thanks again.

Comment: So I delete tthis question and make another with part on right and chapter on any page question?

Comment: @DenysPotapov No roll back this question to what I answered. Then post a new question with the updated question as it is not really related to this one/